# I heard from an acquaintance that it is possible to programmatically cut Google's reCapcha so that it doesn't show image verification, is this true?

Tags: selenium, puppeteer

I heard from an acquaintance that it is possible to programmatically cut Google's reCapcha so that it doesn't show image verification, is this true?
I don't really believe it, but I'd like to find out if there is a way to prevent image verification.

In general, I think you can use the solver service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAPTCHA, short for Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart, is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try! There are two primary strategies to get around CAPTCHA checks:

Disable CAPTCHAs in your test environment
Add a hook to allow tests to bypass the CAPTCHA

The main purpose of re captcha is wont automate site by using 3 rd party tools like selenium etc

Comment: That's how it's written in the selenium documentation.
I guess you can't disable image authentication on someone else's site.

Comment: You cant disable CAPTCHA from other site